# Display Product attributes below products in one html table?

Tags: python, django

I`ve got a table displaying all products. I would like to display the product attribute for each product name. Is it possible to do this in one table like shown below?

[image: Product Table]

Thank you

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    attribute = models.ManyToManyField(ProductAttribute)

class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    property = models.CharField(max_length=20) # eg. "resolution"
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20) # eg. "1080p"
```

**file.html**

```
{% for product in products %}
<tr>                                            
    <td style="font-weight:bold">{{ product.name }}</td>
    
    <td>{{ product.productattribute }}</td>                                       
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def productlist_details(request, shop_id, productlist_id):
    shop = Shop.objects.get(pk=shop_id)   
    products = Product.objects.all()
    productattributes = ProductAttribute.objects.all()
   
    context = {
                'shop': shop,                 
                'products': products,
                'productattributes': productattributes,                                       
            }            
    return render(request, 'productlist_details.html', context)
```

Comment: might want to look at the ifchanged template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `ifchanged` tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) you could do something like:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <tr>                                            
        <td style="font-weight:bold">{{ product.name }}</td> 
    </tr>

    {% for attribute in product.attributes.all %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ attribute.property  }}</td>                                       
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have tried it, the only issue I`ve got is that the product attribute is not displayed. Can we display the property by doing this:{{ product.productattribute.property }}? Is that correct? I have added the views.py

Comment: sorry about that @Steve I missed that inner loop on attributes. Updated answer. In this case you don't need the ischanged. I was thinking you had it all in one table (too late at night to be on here for me)

Comment: not a whole lot of documentation on this callable (that I could find). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/optimization/#understand-cached-attributes

Comment: little sample here: https://gist.github.com/johngag/4184550

Comment: After working a couple of hours on it. It works the way your wrote it.Thank you,

Comment: I hope you don`t mind @AMG, do you mind having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/66356910/13613237 Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{% for product in products %}
<tr>                                            
<td style="font-weight:bold">{{ product.name }}</td>

<td>{{ product.attributes.property }}</td>                                       
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```